# vi: paste at top of file

Tags: vim, editor, vi, paste

One thing that's bothered me with vi is that paste (p) inserts lines *after* the line I'm on, which makes it impossible for me to insert things at the top of a file.

For instance, say I'm going through and adding a UTF-8 declaration to the top of a few files:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

yy and it's yanked.  Good.

I switch over to another file, gg to get to the top, and p to paste, and I end up with something like this:

```
import sys
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

which is not what I want.

Now, I'm always finding new things I can do with vi, so I was figuring that this was something I should be able to do, but just didn't know how to.  Searching, however, doesn't provide very useful results, as everybody and their mother has a vi(m) cheatsheet, with both the p and gg in it.  Thus, I come to SO: is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: As an aside - basically everything you would want to do is possible in vim. Some cool new things I've learnt about lately are changing a line up to a certain point (ct?, where ? is the character that you want to modify up to) and dropping back to your shell to execute commands (!cmd, ie !ls)

Comment: Well, yes, I figured it was possible; the problem is that with so many things you can do, it's sometimes hard to find what you want in any sort of reference.

I'm also a bit limited in that I use an editor with vi-emulation, so vim-specific things don't help me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`P` (capital) inserts above/before, as `p` (lower-case) inserts below/after.

`o` and `O` are similar.  `o` inserts a line after the current one, and `O` inserts before.  I use those commands frequently.

You can get to the beginning of the file using `[[`, `1G`, `gg`, or `:1<CR>`.

Comment: Very much correct.  I remember the days of not knowing that -- a long time ago.

Comment: Ah hah!  I knew about o and O, but I didn't make the connection to p.

Comment: @gahooa, I remember the dark ages where I didn't know about 'a' and always used 'i' and had to delete characters at the end of lines every time I wanted to append something.  xD

Comment: I remember using cl instead of s. And the examples could never stop.

Comment: gg also moves the cursor you to the first line

Comment: @das_weezul, You're right.  I've learned that since posting this.  I'll update my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

`:1put!` to put the text before the first line without having to move the cursor there.

`:1put` to put the text after the first line.

https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aput